# APIs Route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, routes

I have a route like this in `api.php:`

```
...
Route::resource("infos",PaymentController::class)->only([
      'show','store'
  ]);
...
```

And when I call my API like these:

- /api/infos/ABC123 => success with Status Code: 200 (in access.log)
- /api/infos/ABC123/ => there area 2 log (Status code: 301; then Status code 200)
- /api/infos/ABC123//// => there area 2 log (Status code: 301; then Status code 200)

Why when I add slash symbols, there are 2 line in access.log?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.htaccess` file that ships with Laravel has a section in it that strips trailing slashes by using a redirect.

This is from the `.htaccess` file, which [can be found here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v8.6.6/public/.htaccess#L12-L15):

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

So, the first line you're seeing is the redirect triggered by this `.htaccess` code, and the second line is the final request without the slash.

Comment: How do I prevent the second (or third) line (`/api/infos/ABC123/` and `/api/infos/ABC123///`)? I've tried to comment those lines on `.htaccess` but requests still success!

Answer (score 0):

Because when you add / then Laravel redirect it to address without /.